# Is It possible to compile a latex document via Angular 9?

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf, latex, pdflatex

I would like to compile and generate PDF files using latex in Angular 9.

In other words, I'd like to know if it is possible, and how, to compile a document via Angular and Pdflatex. The client would insert their data as a JSON data structure (or javascript object), together with a template name for the end document layout.

Do you know if something similar, already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [ng-katex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-katex) library to display tex data(like formulas) to layout. You can then convert HTML to pdf.